# Problem in publishing a solution in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution with 2 projects and I want to publish this application. When I try to install I get a problem. It says that it can't find a txt file I'm using. In my application, I use 2 other txt files, as well, and it doesn't show a problem regarding those 2 txt files. The error is shown below. Does anyone know what the problem might be? Thank you in advance!

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Δημήτρης\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\16302ORR.AW8\MB0AX4OD.0OL\auth..tion_4deb94c49aed6906_0001.0000_30081526368df596\checkStatus.txt'.
File name: 'C:\Users\Δημήτρης\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\16302ORR.AW8\MB0AX4OD.0OL\auth..tion_4deb94c49aed6906_0001.0000_30081526368df596\checkStatus.txt'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
   at AuthenticationApplication.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5444 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
AuthenticationApplication
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Δημήτρης/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/16302ORR.AW8/MB0AX4OD.0OL/auth..tion_4deb94c49aed6906_0001.0000_30081526368df596/AuthenticationApplication.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
```

******* *JIT Debugging* *********
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

```
<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
```

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

The file don't exist.

The files are created on runtime?

If not include them on your solution and mark them as 'Content' and choose the copy option 'Copy Always','Copy if new','Don't Copy'.

Comment: I included all three text files and marked them as Content and to be copied always. The problem stays the same...

Comment: The files are not created on runtime, I created them on my own.

Comment: I wanted to add that the publishing phase is successful. After this when I try to install the application, I get this error...

Comment: Are you deploying with a click-once publish. Check if the files are included project properties / publish properties / application files.
Also on publish options, on deploy uncheck the "use .deploy file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties on both the files that work and the one that does not. Chances are you have the problem file set so it does not copy, which cascades to not publishing.

Comment: I included all three text files and marked them as Content and to be copied always. The problem stays the same...

Comment: I wanted to add that the publishing phase is successful. After this when I try to install the application, I get this error...